# Jenkins email-ext plugin Send email to a group

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-email-ext

Is there a way you can send an email to a distribution list? This is not working as only the individual email addresses are working fine. Is there any setting that i am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dealt with this issue and found out it had to do with mail server restrictions put in place by Sys Admins at my workplace.

A lot of places have rules in place regarding which users or servers can access distribution lists, so the first thing I would do is ask your SA team if such restrictions exist.

Another thing to try (as another answer stated) is setting default content type to `text/html` - assuming above restrictions aren’t the cause.

Comment: So the issue is not with plugin or the version of the plugin I am using?

Comment: I can say that I have the most current versions of Jenkins as well as the email-ext plugin installed and I send out regular, daily email notifications to an email distribution list successfully. I would start by asking your SA's if they have any restrictions on who/what can email the distribution list you are attempting to send an email to via Jenkins. These restrictions are more commonly implemented than you'd think.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue with this plugin. I could send emails to individual users but not to groups/DLs.

Try to set the default content type to HTML (text/HTML) and it will start to work.